# Text message in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this in my `MailableRecover` class

```
return $this->subject('Password Reset')
                ->view('mail.html.recover-password')
                ->text('mail.plain.recover-password');
```

How can I tell the code to use text version of email when sending text(sms) messages

```
Mail::to($user->mobile_number .''. $user->mobile_carrier, $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name)
     ->queue(new MailableRecover($user));
```

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion that you can send an email via SMS?

Comment: @Namoshek That's actually very possible (OP is doing SMS-via-email, not email-via-SMS). Most US providers have an email address for every mobile phone number. AT&T's is `##########@txt.att.net`, Verizon is `##########@vtext.com`, etc. They are *very* heavily spam filtered, though.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the heads up, wasn't aware of that.